# GLTF : Metalness difference between my scene and THREE.JS editor https://threejs.org/editor/

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I've got a gltf file. When I import it inside the Three.js editor (https://threejs.org/editor/) I get a [correct result](https://michaelg.fr/stackoverflow/editor.png) when I add an environment map.

On the other hand, when I import my gltf in my project scene I've a [different result](https://michaelg.fr/stackoverflow/project.png). Even when I use the very same HDRI image. The metalness is way too shinny in this case.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thank you.

```
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

new RGBELoader()
    .load( 'royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function ( texture ) {

        texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
        scene.environment = texture;

    } );

loader.load(
    './gltf/canette.glb',

    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( gltf ) {

        obj = gltf.scene;

        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf.scene );
        action = mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[ 0 ] );
        

        //obj
        scene.add( obj );
    }
);
```

**EDIT :**

[Here](https://michaelg.fr/stackoverflow/live)'s a live demo.
[Here](https://michaelg.fr/stackoverflow/live/gltf/jeff/)'s the gltf model.

Comment: Do you mind demonstrating the issue with a live example?

Comment: @Mugen87, I don't mind at all. Question updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are using a code snippet which does not match your actual `three.js` version. You have to use at least `r131` (or better the latest one `r141`). Right now, you are using `r129`.

If you use `three.js` versions below `r131`, you have to use `PMREMGenerator` to prepare the environment map that you apply to PBR materials. Starting from `r131`, the engine is doing this for you so you don't have to worry about `PMREMGenerator` at all.

Comment: Thank you VM I simply needed to update my three.js version...